# Split file into n files using csplit (or similar tool)

Tags: split, csplit

I have a huge file with the following pattern:

```
ABC
line 1
line 2
line 3
ABC
line 1
line 2
ABC
line1
ABC
line 1
line 3
```

Using `csplit` tool I'm able to split the file above according to `/ABC/` pattern into 4 subfiles:

```
csplit -z input.txt /ABC/ {*}
```

I wonder how to manually specify the number of desired output files.

Comment: Do you require that the splitting happens at the same points where `csplit` would have split, i.e. on the `ABC` lines?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, file should be split according to the `/^ABC/` line.

Comment: If your split is determined by the content of the file, then I’m not sure what you’re asking for. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: @bxm Sorry, maybe my question is not clear. In the current setting, the toy file is splitted into four files using the provided `csplit` command. Is there a way to manually specify the number of output files, e.g. 2?

Comment: @bmx They want the splitting to be done on the `ABC` lines, but not on _every_ such line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk` - not exactly what you wanted, but might do the trick.

Idea: print n lines into a part-file and then search for next occurence of your pattern before creating a new part-file.

Disadvantages:

- If you have large blocks and just skipped the beginning of such a block, some files might become far bigger than others.
- Original file not removed (i.e. twice the space needed).
- As written, the match line has to be exactly `ABC` (no tolerance vs. other words on same line - could be adjusted)
- Works by setting number of lines rather than desired number of output files (estimate by line number of input file)

`akw`-script

```
BEGIN{
    outfile="part_"++i
    j=0
    }
{ 
    j++
    #block size set to at least 10 lines in this example
    #if threshold line number reached: search for next keyword,
    #then increase part file name counter and reset line threshold counter
    if ( j>=10 && $0 == "ABC" ) { outfile="part_"++i ; j=0 }
    print > outfile
}
```

Execute via

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```